# Recreate specific device screen size in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, screen

I would like to create a layout specifically for a device having the following display specification

480 x 800 pixels, 4.3 inches (~217 ppi pixel density)

The following is the closest thing i could get setting to

[image: My Custom Device]

However the resulting layout is quiet different with the one i get

This is what it looks like in Eclipse

[image: Rendered in Eclipse]

This is what it looks like in Device (Genymotion)
[image: Rendered in Device]

I have set up the following layout folder:

layout (baseline)
layout-xhdpi
layout-hdpi

Can anyone help me with this?

*note:* somehow when i use layout-large, layout-normal, and so on the respective layout does not loaded correctly. It always revert back to baseline layout.

Comment: Your buttons at the bottom of the screen are nice, but the markers under the image, please change the layout background or maybe make some round corners or strokes. just saying :D liked the UI structure

Answer (score 0):

You should read [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html). Layout (-large, -normal, etc) are determined by the physical size of the device (in inches). the drawable resources (-xhdpi, -hdpi, -mdpi, etc) are determined by the screen resolution.

If you want to clone the device (480x800, 4.3 in) than the emulator will use the layout-normal (or baseline) and the drawable-hdpi resources (if I did the math correctly)

If you are still unsure which layout will be loaded you can check during runtime using something like this:

```
if ((getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & 
    Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == 
        Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE) {
    // on a large screen device ...

}
```

Comment: I am not too concern about the resources in the drawable at the moment. I am trying to achieve the desired layout for this specific device i mentioned. What i do not understand is how to reflect the result seen on the device (in this case emulator) to eclipse.